# What does "Ord" mean?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a question as follows:

Solve for $x: ord\:29(x)=7$.

I have never seen Ord before I have an exam and something like this will come up so can someone just tell me how I would go about doing this?

Comment: give a reference on such a notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the multiplicative order (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) which means that $x^7 \equiv 1 \mod 29$ where, in this case, $7$ is the smallest number satisfying this equation.

Comment: I agree with @Tim. It would just be a guesswork afterall